# getting strange error in sh/ksh file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, jar, ksh

i have following sh script-

```
YUI_PATH=www/code/build/b2b_dev/yuicompressor-2.3.5.jar
DIR=www/code/build/b2b_dev/build/web

cd $DIR
echo $DIR

for i in `find . -name *.js -o -name *.css`
do
   echo $i
   ${WAS_DIR}/java/jre/bin/java -jar $YUI_PATH -o $i $i
done

echo "All js and css files recursively within $dir have been compressed!"
```

when i ran this file i got this error- `/www/code/build/b2b_dev/yuicompressor-2.3.5.jar is not found.`

but i have this jar at right location, inspite of it i am getting this error.

can Any body figure out why i am getting this error because i am failed to do so.. :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your script changes to the directory `www/code/build/b2b_dev/build/web`. It then tries to look for the jar `www/code/build/b2b_dev/yuicompressor-2.3.5.jar`
 *relative to the current directory* and cannot find it.

I would recommend using absolute paths instead.

Example:

```
BASE_DIR=/full/path/to/www/code/build/b2b_dev
YUI_PATH=${BASE_DIR}/yuicompressor-2.3.5.jar
DIR=${BASE_DIR}/build/web
```

If you must use relative paths, change to:

```
DIR=www/code/build/b2b_dev/build/web
YUI_PATH=../../yuicompressor-2.3.5.jar
```

Comment: @dogbane-i think, i have done the same thing..i am using absolute path

Comment: they don't look like absolute paths because they don't have a leading `/`.

Comment: in my script i have done the same thing which you have written in your example(absolute one)...just for understanding purpose i have written paths without base_dir in question...

Comment: that is a typo mistake...in my script my base dir is `/www/code/build/b2b_dev` this one

Comment: what happens when you try `ls -ltr /www/code/build/b2b_dev/yuicompressor-2.3.5.jar`

Comment: it 's giving me the information about this jar file like this `-rwxrwxrwx    1 srvwas   webadmin     851304 Dec 30 03:42 /www/code/build/b2b_dev/yuicompressor-2.3.5.jar`

Comment: add `ls -ltr $YUI_PATH` to your script, before the java command and see what happens.

Comment: i get the same information as i got earlier...i am not getting what's going wrong man... :(